# wp_list_categories not excluing multiple ids

Tags: categories, exclude

I recently updated to WP 4.4 and im using this code:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'            => 'ID',
    'show_count'         => 1,
    'taxonomy'            => 'portfolio-type',
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'echo'               => 0,
    'title_li'           => '',
    'exclude'            => '115,161'
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

it's only excluding the first id 115, and ignoring other IDS, any solution for this?

Comment: Are you 107.2% sure that those are the correct ID's? Contrary to what the Codex says, `wp_list_categories()` also accepts an Array() for `exclude` so maybe pass an array of IDs: `array( 115, 161 )`

Comment: yes, im 108% sure the IDS are correct, let me try with array

Comment: @Howdy_McGee  tx! array did the Job seems something is wrong in 4.4 it only works with array and not with normal string:

'exclude'
(array|string) Array or comma/space-separated string of term IDs to exclude. If $hierarchical is true, descendants of $exclude terms will also be excluded; see $exclude_tree. See get_terms().

if u like to answer the question to accept it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a Codex error and that the string that `exclude` parameter expects for `wp_list_categories()` is really meant for non-hierarchical tags, such as `blue,red` where hierarchical you *need* to pass an array of integers:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'            => 'ID',
    'show_count'         => 1,
    'taxonomy'           => 'portfolio-type',
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'echo'               => 0,
    'title_li'           => '',
    'exclude'            => array( 115, 161 ),
);
wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Always cross reference [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) with [Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)!